# Radio buttons in multiple nested ng-repeats (angular + JSON)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to replace  tags with radio buttons inside ng-repeats with angular and json. I display a list of products that have sub products. I would like to be able to put a radio button beside each sub product (eg. Product1-Type1)  and group them by the parent product code (eg. Product1) If a user selects a sub product, the "Selected" value would be set to **true** and the other sub products would be set to **false**. And also call the displayFullPricing(prices) function.

Here is the code used to display the json (working)

```
<div ng-repeat="product in groups.Products">
<h3>{{product.Code}}</h3>
<div ng-repeat="prices in product.Prices">
    {{prices.Code }} - {{prices.monthly.RetailPrice}}
    <a ng-click="displayFullPricing(prices)">select</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And the json I am using...

```
{
"ID":"",
"Groups":[
    {
        "Products":[
            {
                "Code":"Product1",
                "Prices":[
                    {
                        "Code":"Product1-Type1",
                        "Monthly":{
                            "RetailPrice":2,
                            "MinimumPrice":4
                        },
                        "Selected":false
                    },
                    {
                        "Code":"Product1-Type2",
                        "Monthly":{
                            "RetailPrice":5,
                            "MinimumPrice":2
                        },
                        "Selected":false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Code":"Product2",
                "Prices":[
                    {
                        "Code":"Product2-Type1",
                        "Monthly":{
                            "RetailPrice":7,
                            "MinimumPrice":3
                        },
                        "Selected":false
                    },
                    {
                        "Code":"Product2-Type2",
                        "Monthly":{
                            "RetailPrice":2,
                            "MinimumPrice":8
                        },
                        "Selected":false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Could anyone help me achieve this? I had tried moving ng-click into a radio button but it didnt work. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gr0WWJu8sK7UhwzwdR4N?p=preview) for you.

Key thing is giving same name for radio groups so I give name with using their parent product.

```
<input type="radio" name="group-{{product.Code}}" ng-model="subProduct.Selected">{{subProduct.Code}}
```

for function call you can use `ng-click`.

```
<input type="radio" ng-click="displayFullPricing()" name="group-{{product.Code}}" ng-model="subProduct.Selected">{{subProduct.Code}}
```

Comment: That looks good - but the only issue is that it is not updated the selected value to true/false in the JSON. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Josethehose normally radio buttons are used for multiple choice for one model, so if you insist to use radio buttons in this example you should write custom function which set clicked button model true other ones false.

Comment: @Josethehose I updated plunker for your wishes check it please

Comment: That worked! Thank you! May the beer fairy be good to you this weekend.